# Automatically resizing inline-block-div

Tags: html, css

So, basically I have a header including a logo and a menu. Normally I layout them with flex, but I want to have a fallback for older browsers, so I'm trying to align them with `inline-block`. I'm not using `float` because I want the menu to be vertically aligned in the middle. The problem is that when the browser window is getting more narrow, the image is not getting smaller. Instead the menu is pushed out of the viewport and I have no idea why and how to change this.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/gwmfqg7t/1/

**CSS**

```
.header-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dashed olive;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

nav.menu-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  padding: 2px;
}

ul.menu {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 2px;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed brown;
  margin: 2px 10px 2px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
 <div class="logo">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Wikipedia_banner_2.png">
 </div>
 <nav class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarioZ' solution is valid. I come up with one that does not require to set a width to the logo, as long as you allow to change the requirements a little so that `display: table` is allowed. Table is supported since IE8, the other browsers share the same support matrix for inline-block.

```
.header-wrapper {
   width: auto; /* instead of 100%, see comments */
   display: table;
}

.logo, .menu-wrapper {
   display: table-cell;
}

.logo img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwmfqg7t/6/).

Comment: I read several times that `display: table` is not recommended for layouting, but apparently there is no other method. Is there a possibility to set the width of the logo cell to be the width of the logo? Otherwise there is a gap between the logo and the menu...

Comment: Yes, this is possible by setting the width of the header-wrapper to `auto`, which is the default value so you just need to remove the 100%. I've [updated the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwmfqg7t/6/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a flexible width to `.logo` and `.logo img` elements. Like:

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dashed olive;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 25%;
}

.logo img {
  width:100%;
}
```

To make it more responsive you can add a media query like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ul.menu li {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  }
  .logo {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    }
}
```

[Try and resize the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarioZG/gwmfqg7t/5/)

Comment: Hm, I tested this, but the menu can still leave the viewport. If the browser is too narrow there is not enough space when the logo has a fixed with (even in percent).

Comment: I updated somthing that can help @0711master and check Marvin's answer too ;)

Comment: Yeah, I would have used media queries anyway ;), I was just wondering if there is some "normal" method to prevent this behavior...